Visited wordpress appearance > theme page and theme disappeared
I went to the Appearance > Theme page, literally did nothing else, and my theme on the site disappeared and site picked up the wordpress default.
The theme is not shown in the theme page any longer. I had to restore back my database to recover.
What could possibly have caused this?

This sounds like, for one reason or another, the theme directory/files became corrupted.  Do you have auto-updates enabled?

Thanks @TonyDjukic I'll take a look, thanks for the pointer.
